# Protect from httrack laravel webiste

Tags: laravel, web, robots.txt, httrack

I have added below rules in my Laravel website https://example.com/robots.txt

```
User-agent: HTTrack
```

Disallow: /
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /

User-agent: Bingbot
Allow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow:

But still my website has been downloaded by httrack copier. So how to prevent being copied by httrack and similar tools.

Comment: robots.txt is more what you'd call guidelines than actual rules

Comment: No other rulles defined in txt file.